# How to remove part of previous string

Tags: powershell, sql-server-job

I'm currently working on a SQL Server JOB file that contains the following code

```
@active_end_date = 99991231, 
@active_start_time = 0, 
@active_end_time = 235959, 
@schedule_uid = N'59cbfb7d-67c7-495c-810d-0ca7a6357f9c'

IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
```

I'm using PowerShell to remove the `@schedule_uid` with this code:

```
$orgineel_localfolder = "C:\Users\Desktop\Jobs_from_Server\aangepast"

$stringtorremove = '@schedule_uid='

$files = Get-ChildItem $orgineel_localfolder *.sql 

ForEach ($file in $files)
{
    $linenumber = Select-String $file -pattern $stringtorremove     
    $removecomma = $linenumber -replace",",""

    $fileName = "C:\Users\EX27740\Desktop\Jobs_from_Server\Orgineel\" + $file.Name.replace("_Orgineel","_nieuwe") # Vervangt alle Orgineel maar niet erg script blijft goed

   (Get-Content $file.fullname) -notmatch $stringtorremove | Out-File $fileName
    }
```

My problem is that in the previous line `@active_end_time = 235959,`. Because the data in this line is not always `@active_end_time`, I want to get the line number of this line by retrieving the line number of the line that I will remove -1.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi thought I post my solution for this if anyone else ever got a similar question:

```
$orgineel_localfolder = "C:\Users\Desktop\Jobs_from_Server\aangepast"

$stringtorremove = '@schedule_uid='

ForEach ($file in $files){
#gets the line number of the value 
$huidigeregel = Select-String $file -pattern $stringtorremove | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'LineNumber'

if ([string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($huidigeregel )){
'Deze job heeft geen @schedule_uid= '
} else { 
#get the right line by subtracting the current line with -2
$goederegel = $huidigeregel -2
$valuewithcomma = get-content $file.fullname  | select -Index $goederegel
$valuewithoutcomma = $valuewithcomma -replace",",""
$orginalithcomma= Get-Content $file.fullname
}

$fileName = "C:\Users\Desktop\Jobs_from_Server\aangepast\" + $file.Name.replace("_Orgineel","_nieuwe")   

if ([string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($huidigeregel)){
(Get-Content $file.fullname) -notmatch $stringtorremove | Out-File $fileName
} else {
(Get-Content $file.fullname) -replace $valuewithcomma, $valuewithoutcomma -notmatch $stringtorremove | Out-File $fileName }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to get the line number of this line by retrieving the line number of the line that I will remove -1.
>   How can I do this?

To find that line number you can use [LineNumber](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730968.aspx) and subtract 1:

```
$number = (Select-String $file -pattern $stringtorremove |  Select-Object -ExpandProperty LineNumber) - 1
```